# Unable to save and display updated custom multi-select dropdown fields in post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have displayed a custom multi-select dropdown in woocommerce shop_order page. The select2 multi-dropdown works perfectly and display the fields proerply. But I also want to save the selected fields on UPDATE button and once the page reload it will not show the previous saved fields in the box. Here is my code

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rudr_metabox_for_select2' ); 
function rudr_metabox_for_select2() {
  add_meta_box( 'rudr_select2', 'Stock Details', 'rudr_display_select2_metabox', 'shop_order', 'side', 'default' );
}

function rudr_display_select2_metabox( $post_object ) {
  global $wpdb;
?>

<select data-placeholder="Select item..." id="rudr_select2_tags" name="rudr_select2_tags" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select" style="width: 100% !important">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'dvs_stock_details';
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY item ASC");
        foreach($rows as $row){
            echo "<option value='strtolower($row->item)'>$row->item</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
<?php
}
 
 
add_action( 'save_post', 'rudr_save_metaboxdata', 10, 2 ); 
function rudr_save_metaboxdata( $post_id, $post ) {
 
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
 
  if ( $post->post_type == 'shop_order' ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] ) )
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags', $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] );
    else
      delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags' );
  }
  return $post_id;
}


add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rudr_select2_enqueue' );
function rudr_select2_enqueue(){
  wp_enqueue_style('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_enqueue_script('mycustom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mycustom.js', array( 'jquery', 'select2' ) ); 
}
```

Here is the screen when I load the order page it displays all the dropdown lists which is 100% correct.

[image]

but when I add the fields and click UPDATE the page reloads and it didn't save the fields in that post_id and also did not display the previously selected fields.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things is going wrong in your code.

Change this `name="rudr_select2_tags"` to this `name="rudr_select2_tags[]"`
so you can grab the data as an array in the server.

Modify your `rudr_save_metaboxdata` function like this.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'rudr_save_metaboxdata', 10, 2 );
function rudr_save_metaboxdata( $post_id, $post ) {
    if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    } 
    if( $post->post_type == 'shop_order' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] ) ) {
            $stock_data = $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'];
            if( !empty( $stock_data ) ) {
                $stock_data = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $stock_data ); 
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags', $stock_data );
            }
        }
    }

    return $post_id;
}
```

For better security you can use [WordPress nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) while saving data in the database.

Then modify your `rudr_display_select2_metabox` function like this.

```
function rudr_display_select2_metabox( $post_object ) {
  global $wpdb;
?>

    <select data-placeholder="Select item..." id="rudr_select2_tags" name="rudr_select2_tags[]" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select" style="width: 100% !important">
        <?php
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'dvs_stock_details';
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY item ASC");

        // get current item
        $current_item = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'rudr_select2_tags', true );
      
        foreach($rows as $row){
            if( !empty( $current_item ) && in_array( $row->item, $current_item ) ) {
                echo '<option value="'. $row->item .'" selected>'.$row->item.'</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option value="'. $row->item .'">'.$row->item.'</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
<?php
}
```

Better hook for `rudr_metabox_for_select2` function will be `add_meta_boxes` as per the [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)